# Simple Haskell Fibonacci function gets stuck

Tags: haskell, fibonacci

I am running the GHCi console, and typing

```
fib 0 = 0
fib 1 = 1
fib n = fib (n-1) + fib (n-2)
```

and then

```
fib 5
```

and the console hangs and dies with:

> : Out of memory

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the console, you haven't defined a single function `fib` with 3 different cases; you first defined `fib 0 = 0`, then overwrite that with a *new* function `fib 1 = 1`, then finally with a third function `fib n = fib (n-1) + fib (n-2)` that has no base case. You can use

```
> fib 0 = 1; fib 1 = 1; fib n = fib (n-1) + fib (n-2)
```

to correctly define a single, 3-case function.

Note this is primarily a problem starting with GHCi 8, since in previous versions you would have to use `let` to start the definition and would get a parse error on the second line:

```
> let fib 0 = 0
> fib 1 = 1

<interactive>:3:7: parse error on input '='
```

Answer (score 2):

By typing the declarations separately into ghci, each one is read as a separate definition of `fib`, shadowing its predecessors. In other words, you're effectively running

```
fib n = fib (n-1) + fib (n-2)
fib 5  -- infinite recursion here
```

The easiest way to avoid this problem is to put the definition of `fib` into a file.